# What is the Linux equivalent of Inno Setup on Windows?

Tags: software-installation, software-rec, cmake, autotools

Looking to create a Linux installer that will work similar to Inno Setup on Windows (which is a great little tool to create installers on Windows).

My project is really simple (just a couple of folders) so I think that using *autotools* or *cmake* is too much effort.

Is there something that is straightforward like Inno Setup but for Linux?

Comment: What is Inno setup?

Comment: Important to know: Does your project need external dependencies (libraries that are not necessary installed on every system, certain version of glibc)? And: On what systems do you want it to run (only AMD64 or also x86, ARM, whatever?

Comment: My project does not need that, no.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens It's a great little tool to create installers on windows.

Answer (score 5):

The closest, widely-used installer on Linux is [MojoSetup](https://www.icculus.org/mojosetup/), which you’ll see in action on lots of Linux games (including all the GOG.com Linux games).

You’re comparing apples and oranges though: `cmake` and the Autotools are build tools, not installation tools. If you want to ship a binary, most Linux users would expect either a distribution package (typically, `.deb` and/or RPM), or just a tarball containing the installation tree (`/usr/local/bin` with your binary and supporting files in the appropriate places). If you want a simpler build system, you might find [the Meson Build system](http://mesonbuild.com/) interesting.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! I am looking for installation tools and not building tools. Are there some more tools you would recommend besides MojoSetup?

Comment: No; the only other installation tools I’m aware of are [InstallJammer](http://installjammer.com/), which is discontinued, and [InstallAnywhere](https://www.flexera.com/producer/products/software-installation/installanywhere/), which is commercial. It’s quite unusual to rely on installers on Linux systems...

Comment: Sadly, that's one of the things that holds it back.

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question. There is NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) which runs under Windows and Linux. When I remember correctly there is even an integration for CMake.

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page

Furthermore there is the Qt Installer Framework. Its multiplatform, too.

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework